# sed or awk replace first 14 ocurrences

Tags: bash, awk, replace, sed

I have a csv file separated by `,`. Unfortunately the last column is a text field and some of the strings have a comma, so when I try to import the csv to MySQL the last column gets cut sometimes.

**Example of my csv file (15 columns) - 37k lines**

```
Column1  ----------         Col2 Col3  Col4 ----      Col15   
server.domain.tld,IP,Country,City,(...),text random text, text text
```

I need to replace all but the last `,` by `;` so when I import the file to MySQL using `;` as column separator, field 15 wont get cut. Another way could be replace the first 14 ',' by ';'.

**Output I need:**

```
Column1  ----------         Col2 Col3  Col4 ----      Col15   
server.domain.tld;IP;Country;City;(...);text random text, text text
```

**Already tried:**

```
sed 's/,/;/g1-14'
sed 's/,/;/g{1-14}'
sed 's/,/;/g{1,14}'
sed 's/,/;/!14g'
sed 's/,/;/14g!'
sed 's/,/\1;\2;\3;\4;\5;\6;\7;\8;\9;\10;\11;\12;\13;\14;/'
```

Comment: so you don't want to replace the last comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace all of them with another character and then reset from the position 15:

```
sed -e 's/,/;/g' -e 's/;/,/15g' file
```

See an example:

```
$ cat a
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
$ sed -e 's/ /X/g' -e 's/X/ /15g' a
X1X2X3X4X5X6X7X8X9X10X11X12X13X14 15
```

Idea based on [Sed: Replace N first occurrences of a character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21190/).

Answer (score 1):

The below Perl command would replace all the commas with `;` except the last one.

```
perl -pe 's/,(?![^,]*$)/;/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat f
server.domain.tld,IP,Country,City,foo,bar,foo,bar,foobar,text random text, text text
$ perl -pe 's/,(?![^,]*$)/;/g' f
server.domain.tld;IP;Country;City;foo;bar;foo;bar;foobar;text random text, text text
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another thought: quote the last field:

```
sed -r 's/(([^,]*,){14})(.*)/\1"\3"/' <<END
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,a,b,c,d
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,fifteen
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n
less,than,fourteen
END
```

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10,f11,f12,f13,f14,"a,b,c,d"
one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven,twelve,thirteen,fourteen,"fifteen"
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n
less,than,fourteen
```

Comment: I think awk may be better suited for this `awk -F, '$NF="\""$NF"\""' OFS=, file`

Comment: I disagree, you have to find the first N fields first, then whatever is left forms the last field even it it contains commas

Comment: Fair enough, shouldn't it be `{14}` though ?

Answer (score 0):

give this sed one-liner a try:

```
sed 's/,/;/g;s/;\([^;]*\)/,\1/'
```

a little example:

```
kent$  echo "foo,bar,foo,bar,foo,bar,here"|sed 's/,/;/g;s/;\([^;]*\)/,\1/'
foo;bar;foo;bar;foo;bar,here
```

#### I would add a gnu sed with `s/.../.../ge`, though it is a bit longer than the above line

```
sed -r 's/(.*)(,.*)/echo $(echo \1|sed "s:,:;:g")\2/ge'
```

same example:

```
kent$ echo "foo,bar,foo,bar,foo,bar,here"|sed -r 's/(.*)(,.*)/echo $(echo \1|sed "s:,:;:g")\2/ge'
foo;bar;foo;bar;foo;bar,here
```